# Show that $F_1 + F_2 +\dots+ F_n = F_{n+2} -1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the Fibonacci sequence. Show that
> $$F_1 + F_2 +\dots+ F_n = F_{n+2} -1 $$
> for every positive integer $n$ by induction.

This is what I have done so far
$$S(k)$$

$$F_k = F_{k+2} -1 $$

$$S(k+1)$$

$$F_{k+1} =F_{((k+1)+2)} -1$$

$$F_{k+1} + F_{k+2}-1$$

I get confused with the $-1 $.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is aimed at giving some insight into the claim, which hints at the motivation for the induction rather than a worked out proof of the induction itself, but I could add that later on if you wish.

$F_{n+2}$

$=F_{n}+F_{n+1}$

$=F_{n}+(F_{n-1}+F_{n})$

$=F_{n}+F_{n-1}+(F_{n-2}+F_{n-1})$

$=F_{n}+F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+(F_{n-3}+F_{n-2})$

$=F_{n}+F_{n-1}+\cdots+F_4+(F_3+F_4)$

$=F_{n}+F_{n-1}+\cdots+F_3+(F_2+F_3)$

$=F_{n}+F_{n-1}+\cdots+F_2+(F_1+F_2)$

Here we have $F_2 = 1$ added in twice and so

$F_{n+2} - 1 = F_1+F_2+\cdots+F_n$

Comment: I believe $$F_2 = 1$$ is for the left hand side right? so would it be $$F_{1+2} - 1 = F_3 - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1 $$

Comment: @user124557 No. On the right hand side in the last step before I conclude there are two instances of F_2. If you subtract F_2 from both sides you get the final equation. If you flip the final equation from left to right you get the original statement in your question. I've edited my answer slightly to show that $F_{n+2}$ is the original LHS and I'm then step wise expanding the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: you need to tell us that $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ are the Fibonacci numbers.

Hint: $F_{n+2}+F_{n+1}=?$ using the basic recurrence - use this to establish your induction.

Establish the base case, and you are done.

Comment: Did you mean $F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}$?

Comment: @GeoffPointer - no: add $F_{n+1}$ to both sides ...

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought you might have been hinting about how the original question might have had $F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}$ on the right hand side rather than what the OP originally wrote.

Comment: Sorry, having thought a little more about this I realise the original statement in the OP is correct.